# How to fix a MongoDB aggregate $project $filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "data" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "one" : [
        {"user" : 2, "two" : 2},
        {"user" : 1, "two" : 3}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "data" : [
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "one" : [
        {"user" : 2, "two" : 2},
        {"user" : 1, "two" : 3}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to filter in an aggregate (since the data above is from previous stages) so that the one array is filtered to only show one array items where the user is equal to the _id.

The following returns empty one arrays, how to I get the filter to fill in the one array as I expect?

```
db.parks.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 1, 'data.id': 1, 'data.one':
{$filter: {
  input: '$data.one',
  as: 'un',
  cond: {$eq: ['$$un.user', '$_id']}}
}}}]).pretty()
```

Which gives:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "data" : [ { "id" : 1, "one" : [ ] } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "data" : [ { "id" : 2, "one" : [ ] } ] }
```

Replacing '$_id' with '$$un.user' shows all data.one items as expected, so it looks like the problem is in the $eq statement.

How to I get the filter to show the one array as I expect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$data",
            "in": {
              "id": "$$this.id",
              "one": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$this.one",
                  "as": "on",
                  "cond": { "$eq": ["$$on.user", "$_id"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "d",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$d.id", "$_id"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HsBoVCO6hUQ)

Comment: That's works, and you helped me to see a better solution: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VIDZW3iuYo9 - didn't know you could use the $$this in $map

Comment: `$$this` refers to the current element. Since I was not using `as` expression in the `$map` if you can see and that is why I am using `$$this`.